# Comment combiner des passé simples et des imparfaits ?

Tags: temps-grammatical, imparfait, coordination, concordance-des-temps, passé-simple

J'ai un peu de mal avec le choix et la concordance des temps. Quelqu'un peut-il m'aider et m'expliquer comment choisir.

Que faut-il écrire ?

- *Je retrouvais la cabane du montagnard et vis un panneau indicateur.*
- *Je retrouvai la cabane du montagnard et vis un panneau indicateur.*

Answer (score 2):

Il est possible de coordonner des passés simples lorsque deux événements (ou plus) occurrent séquentiellement. Il est aussi possible de coordonner des imparfaits pour combiner des contextes (habitudes, états, évènements en cours, etc.). Mais dans l'usage, imparfaits et passés simples ne sont jamais mélangés.

Pour enchaîner deux évènements dans une narration on peut écrire :

> Je retrouvai la cabane du montagnard et vis un panneau indicateur.

Par contre, puisque voir un panneau est un évènement singulier, à moins de vouloir décrire une autre action pendant que la cabane est retrouvée et que le panneau est vu, ce qui serait un contexte un peu farfelu, ce n'est pas vraiment possible d'utiliser l'imparfait. Le seul cas particulier dans lequel voir le panneau devient une habitude serait le cas d'un ancien rêve, auquel cas la description suivante serait adéquate :

> Je retrouvais la cabane du montagnard et voyais un panneau indicateur.

Mais il ne faut en aucun cas mélanger imparfait et passé simple.

---

It's possible to coordinate simple pasts when two (or more) events happen sequentially. It is also possible to coordinate imperfects to combine two (or more) contexts (habits, states, ongoing events, etc.). But usage dictates not to combine an imperfect with a simple past.

So you'd use the following to chain two narrated events:

> Je retrouvai la cabane du montagnard et vis un panneau indicateur.

Since seeing a sign is usually a single event, unless you want to describe another action while you're both finding the hut and seeing a sign, which would be a quite peculiar context, you can't really use imperfect here.
The only special case I can think of when seeing a sign becomes a habit would be the description of a past dream, in which case the following sounds fine:

> Je retrouvais la cabane du montagnard et voyais un panneau indicateur.

But imperfect and simple past shouldn't be mixed together.

Answer (score 1):

J'utiliserais le passé simple, qui indique une action ponctuelle plutôt que l'imparfait qui indique une action d'une certaine durée :

> Je retrouvai la cabane du montagnard et vis un panneau indicateur.

Comment: Merci pour le vote négatif, c'est sympa ! On peut savoir pourquoi ?